# How to show empty ListView which uses custom adapter to populate data

Tags: android, android-listview

Hello all android developers..

i have a listview which gets initially populated with some list (which is not empty) in onCreate() method. and as user type in search box,the listview gets updated.i use custom adapter to make this work.
Everything works fine.

But i want to show the empty listview initially and then as user type in search box,the listview should get updated with search query. just like searching interface. how do i perform this? any help ?

Comment: Do not set the adapter for list view

Comment: when u click on the search then u can set adapter or make adapter  as visible or invisible  what u want

Comment: Better is to make listview invisible in xml and set it visible on search box's event on which you are updating listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your list invisible in the xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/somelist"
    adnroid:visibility="gone" />
```

If the user search something, you can filter the list and make the list visible again:

```
somelist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: your solution seems to work ,i hide listview in xml file.But i performSearch using TextWatcher in afterTextChanged() method,so as user type the listview is populated with search result,so i can not make the listview visible on every text change operation as it displays me the whole list as before.

Comment: You can wrap the setVisibility call with an IF check (e.g.: if (!somelist.isVisible()) { // set visible }

Answer (score 0):

You can set the null for your adapter, then it will show an empty list to user
and space allocated for list will remain as it is ,

```
yourList.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: when i am passing null list to setAdapter it showing me error as NullPointerException on fetching list.size() in getCount() method of custom Adapter

Comment: you have to initiate your list , like list = findViewById(R.id.listid); and then set the null adapter